# How to clean a git local branch post a merge request on gitlab

Tags: git, merge, gitlab

On a gitlab repository, I had a feature branch `welcome-page`. Once happy with the modification, I have merged it into master directly on `gitlab.com` checking the `squash commits` and `delete branch` options.

Post successfull merge, I have only master on `gitlab.com`. However, locally, `welcome-page` is still there even after a `git gc --prune=all` because of the commit squash I guess.

Is there a simple git local command that would put my local in sync with `gitlab.com` or should I just delete locally the unused local branch?

Comment: Locally `git branch -d welcome-page`.

Answer (score -1):

`git remote prune origin`

Or

`git remote update --prune origin`